# Setting screen size for multiple devices on mobile web application

Tags: ios, css, width, viewport

I am trying to get a legacy web application to run "properly" on mobile devices (where "properly" mainly means tweaking CSS so that text is readable and superfluous images and effects are hidden). Due to various reasons (many graphics files which cannot be changed right now) I have decided on a width of 480px width for phones and 630px width for tablets, and 1024px for desktop browsers.

So far, I have created two CSS groups for smartphones and tablets:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:631px) and (max-width: 1000px) { ... }
```

and

```
@media only screen and (max-width:630px) { ... }
```

which each have a fixed page width (480 and 630 pixels respectively) and some parts of the page modified (for example, the phone version has a dropdown menu instead of a hover menu).

On desktop browsers, e.g. Chrome, this works fine - when I change the window width the page layout changes accordingly. On iPhone and iPad, however, this doesn't work fully:

- the non-retina iPad (768 pixel width) shows a white border left and right to the (630px wide) page, the CSS is selected correctly though;
- the retina iPhone shows the tablet version (since it has 640px width), but I want it to use the lower-resolution version. Same for other hi-res (say >140dpi) displays.

Other tablets and phone (emulators though) also mostly select the right CSS media query group but do not zoom the page to full width.

How do I get the page width always to occupy 100% of the available width, regardless of the device width; i.e. zoom the page to full width? I tried playing with the "viewport" parameter, but this is a fixed parameter that cannot be modified depending on user-agent or real device width (JS hacks that try to do this didn't work so far).

Any ideas welcome!